# Using sed to add a space

Tags: regex, linux, sed, md5sum

I need to add a space between the md5sum and the file name. So my current output is:

```
1be9df543bb5fa37c4b53f0401072f98 file.xml
```

And I need it to be:

```
1be9df543bb5fa37c4b53f0401072f98  file.xml
```

I am a mess with regex/sed but this is what I have and I'm kind of stumped:

```
sed -E 's/([-A-Za-z_0-9]+\.[-A-Za-z_0-9]+).*$/\1  \2/'
```

Output for this is:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 45: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `BASH string substitution`:

```
s='1be9df543bb5fa37c4b53f0401072f98 file.xml'
echo "${s/ /  }"
1be9df543bb5fa37c4b53f0401072f98  file.xml
```

OR sed:

```
sed 's/ /  /' <<< "$s"
1be9df543bb5fa37c4b53f0401072f98  file.xml
```

Comment: Wow that was much easier than I was making it out to be. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to reference two match-groups, but you've only created one (each parenthesized element in the pattern is a group).

I like anubhava's suggestion for its simplicity, but if you **don't** want to turn **every** space into two spaces, change your original regex as follows:

`sed -E 's/([-A-Za-z_0-9]+\.[-A-Za-z_0-9]+)/  \1/'`

Note that all this actually buys you is that you don't insert a space unless the next word has a period in it.

Answer (score 1):

Some `awk` solution:

```
echo "1be9df543bb5fa37c4b53f0401072f98 file.xml" | awk '{print $1"  "$2}'
1be9df543bb5fa37c4b53f0401072f98  file.xml
```

```
echo "1be9df543bb5fa37c4b53f0401072f98 file.xml" | awk '{print $1,$2}' OFS="  "
1be9df543bb5fa37c4b53f0401072f98  file.xml
```